# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0,2) into shape (2,)

Tags: python, k-means

I'm studying on K means but it gets some trouble. Can someone help plz

```
def find_new_centroid(X, labels, j):
    centers = np.zeros((j, X.shape[1]))
    for k in range(j):
        # collect all points assigned to the k-th cluster
        Xj = X[labels == k, :]
        # take average
        centers[k, :] = np.mean(Xj, axis=0)
    return centers
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `labels` is of type `numpy.ndarray` and not a Python `list`